# how to count the repetition of the relationships in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to calculate the number of relationships between two nodes which are repeated more then one time. As i am using `MERGE` clause . So, is there any possibility to calculate if the relationships repeated more than one time. Graphically i can not see because while using the `MERGE` clause all relationships merge if the nodes and relations are the same. But in my data repetitions does exist. For example, if node `A` calls node `B` and this call relationship is more then 10 times. when i will use the `MERGE` clause it will appear only one time which is good to avoid the repetitions in graph. But can i count this repetitions with cypher query or not? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have `(a)-[:CALLS]->(b)` then the way to count the number of CALLS relationships between a and b would be

```
MATCH (a)-[r:CALLS]->(b) 
RETURN COUNT(r)
```

However, you also say that you're using `MERGE` which should only create one `CALLS` relation between a and b.

If you're sure that there are multiple `CALLS` relationships between a and b then either the usage of `MERGE` is incorrect, or these relationships existed earlier before you started using `MERGE`.

Either way, the Neo4j browser (post 2.2) will show you nice curved relationships between a and b if more than one exist, and the query above will confirm that fact.

Comment: Thanks Luanne, the problem is i dont want the repetition of the data in my graph database. so that i can view the relationships between nodes. it means there is no other way to count the merged relationships. right?

Comment: If you use MERGE then you're guaranteed to have at most one relationship between the nodes (provided none existed earlier) so the count will be either one or zero.

Comment: Also note that if `OWNS` has any unique property, it will create a new relationship every time. For example, `MERGE (a)-[:CALLS {created: TIMESTAMP()}]->(b)` will create a new `:CALLS` relationship every time the query executes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the repeated relationships, you can use this query:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH 
    a, b, type(r) as typer, count(r) as countr
WHERE 
    countr>1
RETURN
    a, b, typer, countr
```

For example, if you had this data:

> John - calls -> Sally
>
> John - calls -> Sally
>
> Sarah - calls -> Tom
>
> Amy - calls -> Lily
>
> Amy - calls -> Lily
>
> Amy - calls -> Lily

The query would return:

```
a        b         typer        countr
John     Sally     calls     2 
Amy      Lily      calls     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I use variations of the following in order to review duplicate relationships:

```
MATCH
  (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH
  id(a) AS id_a, id(b) AS id_b, type(r) AS type_r, count(*) AS count_r
WHERE
  count_r > 1
RETURN
  type_r, count_r
LIMIT 10
```

you need to be careful as it is also possible duplicates are valid as they might contain different property values contained within them. However as you've explained you are using MERGE when creating, you should not be getting duplicates. Can you make sure that you are using the right MERGE statement, which requires the relationship to be merged independently of any new or changed values in the nodes belonging in the relationship. You might want to post examples of your code in order to review it properly.

Comment: I tried this out, but it doesn't actually count duplicate relationships. The count will always be 1 even if there are duplicates.

Comment: @Nadine ,  not sure why or when this stopped working. I adjusted for current syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the results graphically...

```
MATCH p=(a)-[r]->(b)
WITH b, collect(p) AS pl
WHERE size(pl) > 1
UNWIND pl AS p
RETURN p
```